# Push notification with subscription for categories

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, subscription

We have an application for viewing the documents for different products. I would like users to subscribe for any product which they use. They have to be notified when any new guide is published for that particular product.

I need subscription to products not to the entire site. Which tool will help to achieve this?

We tried service workers. But it looks like, it will only allow users to subscribe to the entire site and provide notifications for any content newly added to the site.

1) User can subscribe to one/more products

For Example, if a user has subscribed for product A.

He is now viewing a document about **product B**, He should be asked to subscribe to B(since he has not subscribed).

But when he is on a guide for **product A**, he should not be asked to subscribe(since he has already subscribed).

Currently, it is only asking the user to subscribe to the entire site

2) I should be able to provide javascript code to tell the system whenever a new guide is being published.

Comment: Any code of your try?

Comment: You could try OneSingnal, its free and offers quite a lot of features

Comment: a simple way is filter the notification in service worker.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are a lot of services out there. I've only used Firebase and his [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) service service They have a very flexible and easy to use push notifications system. One of its features is [*topic* notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging), that could get this done.

Basically, your users subscribe to the topic of which they want to receive push notificacions. This topics could be you categories.

You will have to handle the checks for if a user is already subscribed to a topic, but that should be easy.